# Load data in a custom module using xml file. Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I want to add another payment method in wizard `Register` payment; So I added this data; but nothing happened. What's wrong, please?
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>  

      <record id="account_payment_method_other_in" model="account.payment.method">
           <field name="name">Other</field>
           <field name="code">other</field>
           <field name="payment_type">inbound</field>
       </record>
       <record id="account_payment_method_other_out" model="account.payment.method">
           <field name="name">Other</field>
           <field name="code">other</field>
           <field name="payment_type">outbound</field>
       </record>
</odoo>

'data': [
        'data/my_file.xml',]
```

Comment: did you declared it in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

you should put the data tag after the odoo one like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="account_payment_method_other_in" model="account.payment.method">
            <field name="name">Other</field>
            <field name="code">other</field>
            <field name="payment_type">inbound</field>
        </record>
        <record id="account_payment_method_other_out" model="account.payment.method">
            <field name="name">Other</field>
            <field name="code">other</field>
            <field name="payment_type">outbound</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

the noupdate="0" means the data will be updated on any upgrade of the module and noupdate="1" means that it will be only inserted/updated just on initial install